# How to deal with "too many columns" in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, partitioning, bigdata

I have 1800 columns and approximately 4 million rows in a tab delimited file. I am trying to load it as mysql relation. Mysql is giving me  `ERROR 1117 (HY0000): Too many columns`. 
I checked on web and found that MySQL is incapable to handle such a big data and some suggestion were to partition the table vertically.

What I am looking for is an example on how to partition this and how to perform a select query on the partitioned tables.

Thanks

Comment: If you have 1800 columns, you might want to normalize a bit.

Comment: 1800 columns is rather... insane.

Comment: Why do you need so many columns? Can you describe what are all these columns?

Comment: They are all features of a patients and I need to have those columns.

Comment: I would call 1-800-NORMALIZE

Comment: @user1140126 - Even if you need all this **data** you do not have to keep them as **columns of a single table**. If, for example, some of these fields represent test results, you can create `tests` table and put all them there.  You can go further and split `tests` into `test_types` and `test_results`, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

You can have as many tables as you want to define a single relation. It is also considered acceptable practice for a couple reasons reasons (performance, security).

You just need to split your csv files and keep tables linked with the same primary key.

To split the csv file you can easily use cut (hopefully no size limits):

```
cut -d"," -f1-1000 patients.csv > cols1000.csv
cut -d"," -f1001-1800 patients.csv > cols1800.csv
```

You can split more if you want of course. For the tables, I understand that you already know how to import. Just use an auto_increment pkey in both tables to keep the relation.